# Transformer core material

Tags: current, transformer

What will happen if transformer core is made of aluminium which is a paramagnetic material?

I know transformer core is made of iron which is a ferromagnetic material. The reason is a small amount of magnetizing current can produce a thousands of times magnetic field inside the core.

This was asked in a interview. Please clarify this.

Comment: You wouldn't have saturation and no hysteresis

Comment: So, what will happen then ? Current will continuosly increase and will burn the winding right ??

Comment: I think the most important thing is that aluminum is a conductor. It will not  act as a transformer core, it would more likely act as a shorted secondary winding of an air core transformer.

Comment: @NikhilKashyap Yes, if your source resistance is zero, your coil resistance is zero and your voltage source is ideal

Comment: Sir but we have wound the windings on the aluminium core. How will it be air core transformer then ?

Comment: What if source is ideal but coil resistance is non zero ?

Comment: @NikhilKashyap then your current is limited to the resistance of the coil

Comment: @laptop2d, please give an answer with a little explanation. I am getting confused.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no significant difference between the magnetic susceptibility of aluminium, and of free space. If that of free space is normalised to 1, transformer iron is in the 2000 to 5000 range, aluminium is 1.000016. So magnetically, the transformer might as well be air-cored.

Aluminium is a good conductor however, better than iron. Even transformer iron has to be formed into insulated laminations, wires or powder to reduce the losses caused by the effective shorted turns that loops of conductor within the core cross-section at right angles to the flux would cause. The same would need to be done with the aluminium core.

Comment: Wiil it behave as a transformer ?

Comment: @NikhilKashyap You've got a clear, verbatim answer to your first question ("will it behave as a transformer") in this answer. You need to read the answers, and understand them. If you can't understand them, ask about what words you specifically don't understand. Your second comment makes even less sense.

Comment: sorry I think due to my weak english I was not able to understand in the first read. I got it now.

Answer (score 5):

A solid aluminium core will act as a shorted turn. If made from insulated laminates of the same thicknesses as a regular power transformer's iron laminates, it will still act like a fairly good shorted turn because aluminium has an electrical conductivity that is much smaller than silicon steel.

But there is no point because aluminium brings nothing to the party; it has no beneficial magnetic properties that can magnify the inductance of a winding (important in power applications); in fact it reduces the inductance because of it acting as a fairly conductive shorted turn.

Comment: Does your graph have a source and context?

Comment: @HarryH [Try this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect)

Comment: Thanks. I was taken aback a bit by your graph which shows Alu-Cu-Fe. Not in the order that I expected, but that's of course because iron has that \$\mu_r\$ in the denominator of \$\delta\$.

Comment: I think skin depth is of less relevance here in a traditional transformer region (50 - 440 Hz).  The **core** (iron) losses are due to current loops in cross section of the laminations.  So if your lamination is 0.5mm thick the current forms a look with current flowing 0.25mm in one direction and 0.25mm in the other direction.  This is smaller that the skin depth and likely not to be affected by that characteristic.  Bulk conductivity effects will likely dominate.  An interesting thing to research though.

Comment: Yes, it's not about skin depth rather than electric losses due to the eddy currents which increase when the thickness of the iron increases. Indeed, at thicker iron laminations, the area of the loop through which the flux goes is larger, and so the induced voltage and 'short circuit' current.

Comment: [This](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0ahUKEwihlvuY28nbAhXLD8AKHYmICSQQFghkMAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebfiles.portal.chalmers.se%2Fet%2FMSc%2FBerglundRagnarMSC.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3_bqWk2F1f_mqSkngnICTW) makes interesting reading - see pg 26.....

Comment: Guys thanks for the observations about laminate thicknesses. It appears I may be incorrect. I've found some evidence that the laminate thickness should be less than the skin depth and I'm still digesting this information and trying to find a 2nd source that explains it better. Certainly Al being a much better conductor than Silicon steel will be the dominant problem with an Al core. The eddy currents in an equivalent Si Fe laminate will be smaller for this reason alone.

Comment: @Andyaka: pg 26 attributes the electrical core losses to eddy currents flowing in the iron around the magnetic flux lines. The magnetic losses are due to the magnetic hysteresis in the iron.

Comment: @Andyaka: There's no reason for the requirement that laminate thickness should be \$\leq\$ skin depth. The determining factor for the laminate thickness is that the thicker the laminate, the larger the loop can be drawn around the flux lines, therefore the larger the area of this loop is, therefore the larger the induced voltage in that loop and the larger the short-circuit current through that loop, hence the larger the losses. It's a balancing of efficiency, accepted heat losses (temperature) and costs. The laminates being thinner than skin depth merely simplifies the loss calculation.

Comment: @HarryH you've convinced me. I shall make amends.

Answer (score 3):

> What will happen if transformer core is made of aluminium which is a
>   paramagnetic material ?

It will act like an air-core transformer with the characteristic low magnetic coupling between the windings and the very high magnetizing current but it will have a much higher core loss, also compared to the iron core transformer.

It will be quite useless for traditional applications.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal magnetic circuit should have high permeability and low resistance. This property is present in the magnetic material of Ferro.

Now, coming to the issue above, the aluminum is nowhere near ferromagnetic properties. It's a paramagnetic material, so there's no need of aluminum.

In reality, raw iron is not used, Grain-oriented electrical steels are used. These are iron-silicon alloys that have low core losses and high permeability required for more powerful and economical electrical transformers.